# Ansible provisioning azure vm with random name

Tags: azure, ansible

I have an Ansible role for provisioning a VM in Azure cloud. The script is working fine but creates a VM with a random part in the name.

```yaml
azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: "{{resource_group_name}}"
    location: "{{resource_group_location}}"
    name: "vm-{{env}}-sql-{{resource_odd_string}}-{{'%01x'|format(item)}}"
    vm_size: "{{resource_odd_vmsizetype}}"
    network_interfaces: "nic-{{env}}-sql-{{resource_agg_string}}-{{'%01x'|format(item)}}"
    image:
      offer: UbuntuServer
      publisher: Canonical
      sku: '18.04-LTS'
    data_disks:
      - lun: "{{resource_odd_data_disk_lun}}"
        disk_size_gb: "{{resource_odd_data_disk_size}}"
    tags:
            env: "vm-{{env}}-sql-{{resource_odd_string}}"
  loop: "{{ range(resource_odd_countstart|int, resource_odd_countend|int + 1, 1)|list }}"
  tags:
    - sql_odd
```

And my variable yaml contains the following variables

```yaml
resource_group_name: ""
resource_group_location: "East US"
resource_odd_subnet: "sqlsubnet"

resource_odd_countstart: "101"
resource_odd_countend: "102"
resource_odd_string: "mine"

resource_odd_data_disk_lun: "0"
resource_odd_data_disk_size: "512"
resource_odd_data_disk_type: "Premium_LRS"
```

When I execute this script, it successfully provisions the VM but its name may be contain a random suffix.

Expected output: `vm-stage-sql-mine-101`, `vm-stage-sql-mine-102`

But I'm getting names like `vm-stage-sql-mine-65`  or `vm-stage-sql-mine-c9` etc. This is the same for NIC names as well.

Comment: You have a hex formatting pattern (`%01x`) and are surprised there are hexadecimal digits in your suffix? `$ printf '%01x' 101` prints `65` on my shell

Comment: An other one liner to spot your problem: `ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg=\"Hexa: {{'%01x' | format(value|int) }} - Decimal: {{ '%01d' | format(value|int) }}\"" -e value=255`. Note that if you only pass ints, `%d` will give the same result. And while you are at it, you can probably simply drop the formatting and use `{{ item | int }}` directly.